# How to assign values to text fields for sum and average

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have 7 columns (E:K) of "Pass/Fail" results. I need to assign a value of "1" for the "Pass" result in 4 (E,F,I,K) of the columns and "2" for the other 3 (G, H,J) columns, along with a "0" for all of the fails. My P/F values start in row 5. Row 1 I am also trying to set up an "average" function to average the individual columns after assigning.

I know how to set up an IF statement if all of the Pass/Fail values were 1/0, but since the columns have different values i cannot seem to make the code work.

I have found some links that are similar but ultimately do not quiet match up for me.

Thank you for any assistance!

Comment: You would have to post your exact effort here on SU and people might be able to find if there are problems with your solution or how to fix it, if you are looking for somebody to just hand over the answer then you are in the wrong place, you can always edit your questions and add more details like screenshot actual code etc

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array formula and two separate functions added together.

For example, to sum `E4:K4`

```
=SUM(IF(E4:H4="PASS",1,0))+SUM(IF(I4:K4="PASS",2,0))
```

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to use this, not just <kbd>Enter</kbd> alone.

This function first runs through the IF statements for each field, replacing "PASS" for 1 or 2 as needed, or a 0 if not "PASS". It then SUMs each result, and adds the two together.

[image]